# Visual Studio, Big Endian data, Intel laptop

Tags: c++, file-io, binary, intel, endianness

I am just trying to write code to parse floats from a binary file written in big-endian.  I have never written code to parse a binary file before, only text files.  Does the fact that I have an intel laptop mean when I use fread it will be little-endian?  Probably an elementary question.  Does my machine determine the endianess of how I read/write a file or is it more dependent on my compiler and/or development environment?

I saw a few byteswapping routine, but I think it would be helpful if somebody can break it down of what is going on.

File info: http://www.sci.utah.edu/~gk/DTI-data/gk2/gk2-rcc-mask.nhdr

Documentation: http://teem.sourceforge.net/nrrd/format.html#endian

Thanks.

Comment: machine determines endian not compiler.  There is a good wikipedia article on this topic.

Answer (score -1):

The `fread` function reads bytes, you will get the bytes in memory exactly as they are in the file. If you have a specification for what the bytes in the file mean, just implement that specification in your code.